# Is it possible to generate the file being included in posix makefile?

Tags: makefile, posix

In gnu make, it is possible to do this:

```
include .deps
.deps:
    ./generate-deps >$@
```

Which will include the .deps file, but it will generate it if it's missing or out-of-date. However, that seems to be behavior specific to gnu make, it has no footing in the posix standard for make. And for example bmake actually does not handle it.

My question is, is it possible to do something like this while having pure posix-compatible makefile? Closest I got is having three makefiles:

Makefile

```
build:
    @$(MAKE) -fMakefile.deps
    @$(MAKE) -fMakefile.real $@
```

Makefile.deps

```
.deps:
    # Some command to generate .deps
```

Makefile.real

```
include .deps

build:
    # The actual build command
```

but that seems convulated as hell. Is there some more simplistic way I've completely missed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a simpler way to do it but it doesn't involve using `include`.

You can do this with a single makefile (assuming the user doesn't override the default goal):

```
build: .deps
        @$(MAKE) -fMakefile -f.deps real-build

.deps:
        # Some command to generate .deps

real-build:
        # The actual build command
```

Comment: Did you really mean to include the `-fMakefile.deps` option in your recipe for the `build` target?

Comment: Yes.  That's the entire point.  Rather than using `include`, you use multiple `-f` options.  Or maybe it would be better to use `-fMakefile -fMakefile.deps` just so the `.deps` comes at the end.  It depends on the needs.  You can't use `include` without multiple makefiles because you need one that _doesn't_ have the include in it, else it will fail if the included file doesn't exist.

Comment: This is significantly more limited than GNU make's facilities because it limits the goal targets you can use.  But for restricted needs it will work.

Comment: Then it's *not* a single-file solution after all (though one of the makefiles is generated).  I thought the point was that the same makefile (only) would be re-used in the recursive `make`, after the top-level `make` run ensured that the rule for `Makefile.deps` was run.  On second thought, though, that might not work / be robust.

Comment: Well, when they said "single file solution" I didn't assume they meant to include the generated makefile in that as well.  If you want to do it with only one makefile in total you have to modify the existing makefile to add dependencies using sed or something, sort of like the old X11 `makedepend`... I don't see any good reason to go back to that sort of pain :)

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you mean!!  Yes, I have a typo in my makefile.  Will adjust.  Dumb...  _fixed_

Comment: I had no idea I can use -f multiple time. That's interesting way to do it. I'll give it a try, thanks :)